# How to read Pandas data header when it splitted in columens like xls

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which is splitted in columens like xls file and when I tried to get the header using list(pd.read_csv(path)) I got a list with one string like ['header1;header2;header3;......']
How can I got the header in list of strings ['header1','header2','header3',....]

Answer (score 1):

I think you haven't defined the separator with your path. It should be:

```
pd.read_csv(path, sep = ';')
```

Comment: it worked but I got a nother Problem that when a normal csv(comma separated) it return to the first problem

Comment: Hi, it should not happen, did you try restarting your kernel and run again?

Comment: the main problem that there are csv separated with ";" and another with ","